# PowerBI Desktop e erro com R (GGPLOT)

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

Eu estou realmente preso e preciso de ajuda.

Depois de instalar o R ​​3.5.1, recebo esta mensagem de erro nas visualizações do  R no Power BI Desktop que estava trabalhando anteriormente.

> "Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2': package
>   'scales' was installed by an R version with different internals; it
>   needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version."

Eu já tentei:

- reinstalar o R 3.5.1
- resintalar RStudio
- reinstalar ggplot2 e o pacote de escalas
- reinstalar todos os pacotes
- reinstalar o PowerBI

Mas ainda não esta funcionando.

Considerações:

- Minhas visualizações estavam funcionando bem antes da instalação do R 3.5.1
- Minhas visualizações estão funcionando corretamento em outros computadores

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Tente reinstalar o pacote `scales` nesta nova versão do [tag:r]. E veja se o erro continua ocorrendo.

Comment: No forum do powerBi tem uma pergunta bem similar que pode auxiliar: [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/R-Visual-Rcpp-package-error/td-p/471272)